# How to close a native browser in phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am opening native browser using inappbrowser plugin in phonegap using this code

```js
 var ref=  window.open("http://www.google.com", '_system', 'location=no');
```

But the problem is I could not close it using

```
ref.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `'_system'` you open another app (usually the native browser), you can't close it.

The `ref.close();` only works if you use the `'_blank'` parameter.